# Templated function inside class, error when moving to header file?

Tags: c++, templates

I have this templated function inside a class.
This is implemented in a file named Mtry.cpp

```
class Mtry
{
public:
    template <typename DerivedV, typename DerivedF, typename Scalar>
    static void cotmatrix(
        const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV> & V,
        const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedF> & F,
        Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar>& L);
};



template <typename DerivedV, typename DerivedF, typename Scalar>
void Mtry::cotmatrix(
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV> & V,
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedF> & F,
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar>& L)
{
    // Implementation...
}
```

I have no problem when using that code.
However, if I move the declaration towards Mtry.hpp and the implementation to Mtry.cpp I get an undefined reference

Mtry.hpp:

```
class Mtry
{
public:
    template <typename DerivedV, typename DerivedF, typename Scalar>
    static void cotmatrix(
            const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV> & V,
            const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedF> & F,
            Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar>& L);
};
```

Mtry.cpp

```
template <typename DerivedV, typename DerivedF, typename Scalar>
void Mtry::cotmatrix(
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedV> & V,
    const Eigen::MatrixBase<DerivedF> & F,
    Eigen::SparseMatrix<Scalar>& L)
{
    // Implementation...
}
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972152/how-to-create-a-template-function-within-a-class-c) where it states that the first code should work. However I couldn't find how to separate the code properly into header and source. How should it be done?